# "Will have already" vs "Will already have" - which is correct?

Tags: grammar

An exchange student just asked me this, and I have no idea despite being a native speaker.  Does anyone know which is correct, and why?  Or are both technically correct?

> I will already have studied that.
>
> I will have already studied that.

My gut feeling is that the second is incorrect because it is a split infinitive, but is that even an infinitive?

Comment: It's not a split infinitive. They're both fine; see [this Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=will+have+already+seen%2Cwill+already+have+seen&year_start=1750&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=10&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwill%20have%20already%20seen%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwill%20already%20have%20seen%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: The infinitive in the sentence is _have_, but -- like all infinitives after modal auxiliaries like _will_ -- it does not use _to_, and therefore is impossible to split, even with an electric infinitive splitter.

Comment: @JohnLawler what about with the Large Hadron Collider? They can split atoms now.

Comment: Yes, but who wants to carry around a large hadron?

Comment: Let alone find somebody with another one to collide with.

Answer (score 0):

*I will have studied that already *

is *more* correct. I remember vaguely the rule, but the verbs should be adjacent to one another:

*will* + *have* + *studied*.